# Magento Cannot Reindex Data

Tags: magento

I m trying to run index management in localhost magento1.5v.When I select all check boxes and hit submit button,nothing is happening.# symbol appending to the url in the address bar.No idea of whats going wrong!

Comment: Has the HTTP request actually been despatched?  Is this a client-side problem maybe?  JavaScript?

Comment: @Nick:How to check it.I checked with firebug.Its seems no error

Answer (score 0):

You can run the indexes via CLI: `php /path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php reindexall`

If this was a fresh install of 1.5 I would try a different browser just to see.  If it was an upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5, I would double check and make sure none of your core files have been modified.

Comment: It is not an upgrade.Just fresh installation in localhost.I have not modified any core files.I tried in several browsers.But no luck.Even other submit buttons not working

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a new product that is not saved properly (i.e. with a SKU) can break the indexing. Check the products all have SKUs and delete them if need be.